# Finding closest input to select in dynamically generated code

Tags: javascript, jquery

So what I'm trying to do is change value of input with id championSpell[] whenever something from dropdown is chosen this code is generated  dynamically so I'm always trying to get the closest/next input after select.

UPDATE: Full code below:

```
<script src="LeagueNotes/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="LeagueNotes/js/champions_list.js"></script>
<script src="LeagueNotes/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<style>
    * { font-family:Arial; }
    h2 { padding:0 0 5px 5px; }
    h2 a { color: #224f99; }
    a { color:#999; text-decoration: none; }
    a:hover { color:#802727; }
    p { padding:0 0 5px 0; }

    input { padding:5px; border:1px solid #999; border-radius:4px; -moz-border-radius:4px; -web-kit-border-radius:4px; -khtml-border-radius:4px; }
</style>

<h2>
    <a href="#" id="addChampion">Add Another Champion</a>
</h2>
<form name="second_form" id="second_form" action="#" method="POST" style="margin: 0;"  >
    <div id="p_scents">
        <p>    
            <label for="p_scnts">
                <input type="text" id="champion[]" size="20" list="champions" value=""  placeholder="Enter Champion's name">
                <datalist id="champions"></datalist>
                <a href="#" id="addGeneral">Add General Change</a><a></a>
                <a href="#" id="addSpell"> Add Spell</a><a></a>

            </label>
        </p>
    </div>
    <br/><input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<script>
    for(var key in champions){
                if(champions.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                    $('#champions').append('<option value="' + key + '">');

                }
            }
    var config = {
                      fillAll: true
                    };

                    document.forms["second_form"].oninput = function(e) {
                      var champion = this["champion[]"];

                      //Force into array
                      if (champion[0] === undefined)
                        champion = [this["champion[]"]];

                      var reached = {
                        valid: 0,
                        unique: 0
                      };

                      var inputs = [].map.call(champion, function(n) {
                        return n.value
                      }).filter(function(n) {
                        return n.length
                      });

                      var valid = [].every.call(champion, function(n, i) {
                        n.setCustomValidity("");
                        if (config.fillAll) return (reached.valid = i, champions.hasOwnProperty(n.value));
                        else return n.value ? (
                          reached.valid = i,
                          champions.hasOwnProperty(n.value) > -1
                        ) : true;
                      });

                      var unique = inputs.slice(0).sort().every(function(n, i, a) {
                        reached.unique = inputs.lastIndexOf(n);
                        return n != a[i - 1];
                      });

                      //Check for valid champions
                      if (!valid) {
                        champion[reached.valid].setCustomValidity("This is not a valid champion, please correct this field and resubmit.")
                      }

                      //Check for duplicates
                      if (!unique) {
                        champion[reached.unique].setCustomValidity("This champion has already been entered.")
                      }

                      this.checkValidity();
                    };

    function change(x, dblchamp){
        if(dblchamp===true){
            if(x==="Passive"){x=0;}
            if(x==="Q"){x=1;}
            if(x==="Q2"){x=2;}
            if(x==="W"){x=3;}
            if(x==="W2"){x=4;}
            if(x==="E"){x=5;}
            if(x==="E2"){x=6;}
            if(x==="R"){x=7;}
            if(x==="R2"){x=8;}


        }else if(dblchamp===false){
            if(x==="Passive"){x=0;}
            if(x==="Q"){x=1;}
            if(x==="W"){x=2;}
            if(x==="E"){x=3;}
            if(x==="R"){x=4;}
        }
        console.log(x);
        return x;
    }
    function val(elm) {
        var championsWithExtraSpells = ["Aatrox", "Elise", "Fizz", "Heimerdinger", "Jayce", "Lee Sin", "Nidalee", "Rek'Sai","Twisted Fate"];
        //var championName = $("#change").closest('input').val();
        //var championName =$("#champion\\[\\]").val();
         var championName = $(elm).closest("label").find("input").val();
        //document.getElementById("champion[]").value;
        console.log(championName);

        if($.inArray(championName, championsWithExtraSpells)==-1){
            var existsInArray = false;}
        else{
            var existsInArray = true;}
         var d = $(elm).val();
        // console.log(d);
        //d = document.getElementById("change[]").value;
        var spellname = document.getElementById("championSpell[]");
        var z = champions[""+championName+""][change(d, existsInArray)];
        test =  $(elm).nextAll("input").first().val('test');
        console.log(test);
        //console.log(d+spellname);
        //test.value=champions[""+championName+""][change(d, existsInArray)];

    }

    $(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents label').size() + 1;
        var j =0;
        $('body').on('click', '#addChampion', function() {
            $('<p><a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a><br><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="champion[]" size="20" list="champions" name="champion[]" value="" placeholder="Enter Champion\'s name" /><datalist id="champions"></datalist><a href="#" id="addGeneral">Add General Change</a><a href="#" id="addSpell"> Add Spell</a><a></a></label></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;
                return false;
        });

        $('body').on('click', '#remScnt', function() { 
                if( i >2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });

         $('body').on('click', '#addGeneral',function() { 
               $(
               '<p><label for="var"><textarea type="text" id="champion[]" size="20" name="GeneralChange[]" value="" placeholder="Enter Description" /><select><option value="buff">Buff</option><option value="nerf">Nerf</option><option value="new">New</option><option value="change">Change</option><option value="bugfix">Bugfix</option></select></label> <a href="#" id="remVar">Remove Change</a></p>').appendTo($(this).next()); 
                j++;
                return false;
        });


        $('body').on('click', '#remVar',function() { 
                        $(this).parent('p').remove();
                return false;
        });

        $('body').on('click', '#addSpell',function() { 
               $(
               '<p><select name="change[]" id="change[]" onchange="val(this)"><option value="Passive">Passive</option><option value="Q" selected>Q</option><option value="W">W</option><option value="E">E</option><option value="R">R</option></select><label for="var"><input type="text" id="championSpell[]" readOnly="true"><br><textarea type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Enter Description" /><select><option value="buff">Buff</option><option value="nerf">Nerf</option><option value="new">New</option><option value="change">Change</option><option value="bugfix">Bugfix</option></select></label> <a href="#" id="addGeneral">Add Change</a> <a href="#" id="remVar">Remove Spell</a></p>').appendTo($(this).next());
                return false;
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just curious, but why `get(0)` instead of `first()`?

Comment: Note: `change[]` is an invalid `id` for jQuery selectors to use as it thinks you want to filter. Why do you have the `[]`?

Answer (score 1):

It is be next sibling of the select, so use [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next), [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest) is used for finding the first ancestor element matching the given selector

```js
function val(elm) {
  var test = $(elm).next("input");
  console.log(test);
  test.val("test: " + elm.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="change[]" id="change[]" onchange="val(this)">
  <option value="Passive">Passive</option>
  <option value="Q" selected>Q</option>
  <option value="W">W</option>
  <option value="E">E</option>
  <option value="R">R</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="championSpell[]" readOnly="true">
```

But it is better to use jQuery event handlers

```js
jQuery(function() {
  $('select[name="change[]"]').change(function() {
    $(this).next().val('t: ' + this.value);
  }).change(); //the last change value is used to set the initial value on page load
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="change[]" id="change[]" onchange="val(this)">
  <option value="Passive">Passive</option>
  <option value="Q" selected>Q</option>
  <option value="W">W</option>
  <option value="E">E</option>
  <option value="R">R</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="championSpell[]" readOnly="true">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.next()` .

```
var test = $(elm).next("input").val('test');
```

your code

```
function val(elm) {
    var test = $(elm).next("input").val('test');
 }
```

Comment: I need to change the value in the next line which doesnt seem to work with this code. 
test.value=champions[""+championName+""][change(d, existsInArray)]; that is what I'm doing next.

Answer (score 0):

This one depends on how robust to changes in the DOM you want to be.

If you may have elements in between, the best option is

```
  $(elm).nextAll("input").first().val('test');
```

`nextAll()` returns all following siblings of the element, used with "input" will return all following inputs only. Then apply `first()`.

If that hierarchy may change, you would go up the DOM to a closest container with both elements, then search down again.

e.g. if these were in two standard `<div class="form-group">` containers (ala a Bootstrap form):

```
  $(elm).closest(".form-group").next(".form-group").find("input").first().val('test');
```

### Update:

You should avoid inline event handlers with jQuery. They do not support all the same features jQuery handlers do and separate the event registration from the event handler for no good reason.

A practical example is here http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/mo94pv8k/

```
$('select').change(function () {
    $(this).nextAll("input").first().val($(this).val());
});
```

### Notes:

- Your current ids are not useful for jQuery use as `[]` is reserved to indicate attribute selection in a jQuery selector. For example `$('#change[]')` is an invalid selector.

Comment: test.value=champions[""+championName+""][change(d, existsInArray)];  I just change the value in that input depending on the dropdown choice

Comment: @Higeath: You need to show all your code in the question, rather than add comments. The snippet you added makes no sense yet, by itself?

Comment: @Higeath:  Until you can add the full code, I have provided an example using a jQuery event handler instead.